# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting blogs and websites for the curious
- cool events or conferences for particular movies or shows
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2089).

Comment: The answer form pre-filling doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hey! How long will the site continue querying the old CP question? I'm still seeing ads pop up from the 2015 one.

Comment: Can I change the "40 KB" in the question to the updated "150 KB" on your behalf?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I offered to do it on the sites I use on the Meta.SE question about the file sizes but she never responded.

Comment: @GraceNote still showing last years ads on all the networks, when is it schedule to go live with this years ad?

Comment: @Ankit Should've gone live when I did the sweep. Looking into it.

Comment: Vote threshold too high, perhaps?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why this question is not **Community Wiki** while **all the others** are?

Answer (score 11):

[image: Visit Mythology.SE!]

Comment: Thats my favourite story of norse mythology!

Comment: Unfortunately, the banner text is a bit misleading. I didn't click the banner first, just remembered it and wanted to have a look. Before trying `mythology.stackexchange.com` I thought "does it indeed have its own full domain?" and tried [mythology.se](http://mythology.se/), which indeed exists, but isn't the site in question.

Comment: @Mario As a general *thing*, SE stands for stackexchange.

Comment: @bleh Yeah, I'm aware of that.

Comment: Maybe a re-post time or something new is coming ?

Answer (score 8):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/movies.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: Oooh, he updated it? Nice!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Name That Movie]

Comment: Adapted from [last year's ad](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1767/49).

Comment: Though, I'm not entirely sure if this ad might not actually have had the contrary effect of attracting *more* ID questions for the simple reason that users didn't get it was referring to *another external* site.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Interested in books as well as movies? Support the Literature proposal!]

Comment: Ohh it's already in commitment stage

Comment: @Ankit Yessss! :-D

Comment: @Ankit I was pleasantly surprised to see a declared non-book person like yourself sign up for it ...

Comment: But don't expect me participating ;D

Comment: @AnkitSharma Well, that actually *is exactly* what is expected from you when you commit to a proposed site.

Comment: Wow fastest accepted community promo ad till now.

Comment: Well, the site is now on beta. Is there a point leaving this around? /cc @AnkitSharma

Comment: @Shadow Why not? Literature SE is still a place where people on this site might want to go, and while it's in private beta (I think) they need to pass through Area 51 to get there. Once we enter public beta I'll edit this and the other CPAs to link directly to the site.

Comment: No need to pass through Area 51 or committing to the proposal in order to join private beta, all it takes is visiting [this special link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature/visit) (tried in Incognito mode, it works.)

Answer (score 6):

[image: I Remember This Movie]

Comment: Adapted from [last year's ad](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1755/49).

Comment: Though, I'm not entirely sure if this ad might not actually have had the contrary effect of attracting *more* ID questions for the simple reason that users didn't get it was referring to *another external* site.

Comment: This site is giving me a "server not found" error right now.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Propose your Community Ad!]

Comment: meta meta meta...

Comment: We can repost this one

Comment: @AnkitSharma Meh, it's not really a work of art. Besides that, we don't really have much of a shortage of ads this year anyway, so I don't think we even need something like this.

Comment: ok, fair enough

Answer (score 4):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The Armory Proposal at Area51]

Comment: proposal is deleted.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair]

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I still fail to see much of a relevance for the ad to this site. But nevermind, I've given my vote and so can others.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 nothing to be took personal here but i can't related with this ad either. I did upvoted the Armory ad but it at-least have shared how its relevent.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - No worries. I'm trying to find ways to ensure MVM&R graduation, which is forthcoming. The crossover in the picture above (in case you or Napoleon don't get it) is that of Paul Walker and one of the cars he drove in *Fast and Furious*. In the movie, both his character and that of Vin Diesel were both mechanics. Just trying to make that connection. If it doesn't work for you, no issues. I'll just keep trying to make my case throughout SE.

Comment: I recognized Mr. Walker and the films this ad references. I still don't feel the connection of the topics, though. But I agree it's at least better than a plain [mechanics.se] ad.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I do know the film and that specific scene too, anyways good luck with mechanics.se .

Comment: Thanks at least for the consideration.

Comment: Filesize is too high.

Answer (score -4):

[image: Support Paranormal proposal]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/96086.png))</sub>